# cython vs ctypes function execution speed

Tags: ctypes, cython

I have a simple plan for my program: do all input parsing and data preprocessing with Python and then pass a lot of structures and call ONCE number-crunching function that I'm going to write in C. 
Here goes my question: what would be faster (in terms of execution speed)? To call C function with ctypes or write it using cython?

Comment: Using Cython vs ctypes to call a single C function a single time is not significantly different. It's more interesting if you write the function in Cython, adding just enough static typing to make it perform well. It may not be quite as fast, but the Cython version is more readable than C and easier to maintain.

Comment: This is going to depend also on the exact code you want to call.  I for one have trouble with cython not being faster than my python (guess I have more tricks to learn) so tend to just use ctypes for this kind of thing.  However for a large class of problems just normal numpy vector operations is almost as fast as using cython or ctypes so look there first as it is easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Given an infinite amount of time to optimize your code Ctypes will probably be faster as you can push as much of the heavy lifting into compiled code as possible.

cython takes python-like code and converts it to C code with lots of caveats and exceptions. If cython were perfect, it would be as fast as coding in the C-API for python. cython is a fantastic tool for quick code dev, but is not quite that perfect yet.

Ctypes will require some manipulation of your input variables to get them into C cleanly. This may not be a problem if you are doing a fair bit of data preprocessing anyway.

As usual you need to decide how important the execution speed is compared with coding time/code readability/code reusability
it would seem strange to me to be only interested in execution speed, and still want to code any of it in python.

Conversely, the general paradigms of python coding would tend to contrast with having large sections of C code held together by python wrappers